# Variable is not being updated in a widget shown on a bottom sheet built using showModalBottomSheet() method in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I have a widget called `testWidget` and it has two children: a `TextField` and a `FlatButton`.

I want to do something with the text typed in `TextField` when the user presses `FlatButton`. Following is the code:

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String textVal = '';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Testing'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (String newVal) {
              textVal = newVal;
              print('Typing: ' + textVal);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Press Button'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Value got: ' + textVal);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem occurs when I show `TestWidget` on a bottom sheet with  `showModalBottomSheet()`, as following:

```
showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => TestWidget());
```

The variable `textVal` is updated inside the `onChanged` callback in `TextField`, but when the user presses the `FlatButton` after typing something, the variable `textVal` is not updated. I have printed the value of `textVal` updated in `onChanged`, and `onPressed` of `FlatButton`.

The output is:

```
I/flutter (11067): Typing: N
I/flutter (11067): Typing: Ne
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New 
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New t
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New te
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New tex
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New text
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New text 
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New text T
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New text Ty
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New text Typ
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New text Type
I/flutter (11067): Typing: New text Typed
(After typing Text, User pressed FlatButton)
I/flutter (11067): Value got:
```

The value printed is ' ', which was the initialization value of textVal, NOT the updated value.

I want TestWidget to be stateless.

Answer (score 0):

This is [sample code for your requirment](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input#complete-example)
You need a `TextEditingController()` and assign this TextEditingController() to you formfield controller property.
For ex,

```
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a text controller and use it to retrieve the current value
  // of the TextField.
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _printLatestValue() {
setState(() {    print(" text field: ${myController.text}");
  });


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: myController,
            ),
FlatButton(
            child: Text('Press Button'),
            onPressed: () {
              print("Value got:  +${myController.text}");
            },
          ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want my widget to be stateless

Comment: Then It's not possible, you have to have a stateful widget to update state throughout the widget.

Comment: this is not the case, statless widgets have data corresponding to there state, but the data and state cannot be updated. in my question i described that widget works fine as expected when it is not child to a ModalBottomSheet. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and reading a lot of things I finally figured out a way, the variable textVal have to be static in order to keep value across widget if widget is child to a persistent bottom sheet. In theory i don't know why but it worked for me. here is the code.

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  static String textVal = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Testing'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (String newVal) {
              textVal = newVal;
              print('Typing: ' + textVal);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Press Button'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Value got: ' + textVal);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```